# Webservice(asmx) returns array, not list

Tags: web-services, list, soap, asmx, webservice-client

I have a deserialization webmethod which returns a list of data in webservice(asmx), and I am calling the method from client-side. However, the method is giving me an array, not a list. I understand that it is because of SOAP response which returns xml format (or something like that..)
Is it possible to return a list? If then, please tell me an idea. 
If not, please teach me an alternative way. (I should not use array...)

service.asmx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public IList<Person> DeserializeJson(string value)
{
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        IList<Person> tableData = js.Deserialize<IList<Person>>(value);

        return tableData;
 }
```

Client.aspx.cs (WebService is my service reference)

```
WebService.Service1SoapClient client = new WebService.Service1SoapClient();
string stream = client.CreateJsonFromDatabase();
List<WebService.Person> tableData = client.DeserializeJson(stream);
```

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Instead of using ASMX, which type of technology should I follow? MVC?

Comment: WCF is the replacement for ASMX (and does much, much, more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web services do not return arrays, and they do not return lists. They return XML. The XML they return is interpreted by the client code as a list, array, or whatever.

If you consume this service by using "Add Service Reference", then you will have a choice of how to treat repeated elements in the XML. You can choose from List, Array, or several other choices.

Comment: Thank you John! So, you are saying that I would be able to convert the XML to choice of List, Array, etc?

Comment: I can see that client.DeserializaJson(stream) returns type of "Client_Projet_Name.WebService.ActivityFlatTableColumns[]", and it's my understanding that this is a type of array? I think I am lost. Could you please give me any example that I can come up?

Comment: Please read my blog post "[How to consume a web service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)" and see if it helps you. Also, "[Basics: How Web Services Work](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/basics-how-web-services-work/)" directly addresses the issue of XML.